# SharedPreferences.Editor putString and putInt error

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

Heres the code:

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES="GamePrefs";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.game);

        SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor=settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString(“UserName”,“JaneDoe”);
        prefEditor.putInt(“UserAge”,22);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }  
}
```

Getting 'syntax error on tokens.delete these tokens' @ putString and 'syntax error on tokens argument list expected instead' @ putInt.
Programming in eclipse.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you copy paste the code from a world document or something? the only thing that I can imagine is that you are using “ instead of "

Comment: Your quotation marks around the strings seem off, they should be like the ones at the `GAME_PREFERENCES` string constant. Happens sometimes with copy&paste, try to delete and type them again.

Answer (score 3):

Your double quotes are "smart quotes". That text must have been copied to/from a word processor or something that automatically converted them.

Use "dumb quotes" in your code.

[more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Smart_quotes)

Comment: Not dumb at all. I've been there trying to debug the same problem.